# Have router connected to Ethernet port in Room 1, works perfectly until I connect another Ethernet cable to a port in another room?

Tags: home-networking

So I have my router set up in Room 1, wifi is working fine and all that.

Go upstairs to room 2, there's an Ethernet port there. I connect my ps4 to that port and then the internet stops working and the router is flashing - no internet / wifi.

Unplug the cable in Room 2, internet works again like a charm.

I can't find any patch panel in the house. I'm also know very little about networking.

Why would I be seeing this behaviour?

Comment: What is the Ethernet port connected to?  Without that information we realistically can't answer this question

Comment: The Ethernet port in Room 1 connects directly to the outside networking / phone cables. As to where Room 2 connects to... your guess is as good as mine, like I said, there appears to be no patch panel. It's almost as if plugging a cable into the port in Room 2 "takes priority over" over the socket in Room 1 and it ceases to work. So strange

Comment: They're probably not Ethernet ports. They're probably RJ-45 jacks and you have assumed they are Ethernet ports. Without a switch at a central

Comment: Stupid phone... with a switch for each port to wire back to it's not possible that you're going to have Internet throughout your house. They're probably running back to your basement and the wires are just twisted together like an old phone system. Voila, only one jack works at a time.

Comment: @SparkyRobinson You should be able to get an electrician to tell you what's up for a reasonable amount of money.  They can at the very least figure out what's connected to what.

Comment: @Appleoddity ah dear, that is rubbish. I think you're right. I don't understand why they would build it like that. I guess it's "run a long rj45 throughout the house" option then

Comment: You can always sort out the wires and patch them in to a switch to distribute internet as needed, but unfortunately it's probably not wired like that right now. It was used for distributing phone not Ethernet.

Comment: Those cables are not suitable for networking as you can see from the table in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair), so you would have to put new cables into the wall.